# Saving numpy array such that it is readily available without loading

Tags: python, database, numpy, save

I have a 20GB library of images stored as a high-dimensional numpy array. This library allows me to these use images without having to generate them anew each time. Now my problem is that np.load("mylibrary") takes as much time as it would take to generate a couple of those images. Therefore my question is: Is there a way to store a numpy array such that it is readily accessible without having to load it?

Edit: I am using PyCharm

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might reduce the image quality or store the images after going through lossy image compression? Otherwise from what I can see, the IO on your hard disk will be your limiting factor in reading the serialized version of the array. Do you also need all the images in memory at once? It might be effective to store the serialized individual images as blobs in a database?

Comment: First question: how much RAM do you have available? Because if it's not significant, then you're going to have to do disk I/O at some point, and that'll pretty much kill any speed you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using a MacBook Air with 4 GB RAM 1600 MHz DDR3. It would be OK for me to load it once upon opening PyCharm. My issue is with understanding how to use it repeatedly in a function (after having loaded it, if necessary).

Comment: Instead of saving all images as one array you could save them individually or in groups with `savez`.  That does a lazy load.  Look also at the memmap mode for `load`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) which is a Pythonic interface to the HDF5 binary data format.

> It lets you store huge amounts of numerical data, and easily manipulate that data from NumPy. For example, you can slice into multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy arrays. Thousands of datasets can be stored in a single file, categorized and tagged however you want.

You can also use [PyTables'](http://www.pytables.org). It is another HDF5 interface for python and numpy

> PyTables is a package for managing hierarchical datasets and designed to efficiently and easily cope with extremely large amounts of data. You can download PyTables and use it for free. You can access documentation, some examples of use and presentations here.

numpy.memap is another option. It however would be slower than hdf5. Another condition is that a array should be limited to 2.5G